# Spark integration

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am newbie to apache spark.
My requirement is, when user clicks on the Web UI, query needs to pass to the Spark cluster and get the data back from the cluster and update the UI.
  I want to know, how to pass the Spark SQL query and get the result set ?

Comment: 1) Setup a REST API to fire-off a Spark action 2) Use AJAX to call out to the REST API for a result... doesn't matter if you are a newbie to Spark, how would you get the result from a SQL database from a Web UI?

Answer (score 0):

Spark has Thrift server for this(running SQL queries through JDBC/ODBC). If you are using Java is your middle layer, use JDBC and connect spark Thrift server as like data base and pass/run what ever SQL(supports Spark).

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would have to write a web application, usually with a REST interface, and implement the Spark SQL inside of the server-side REST handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Livy.
Details : https://livy.incubator.apache.org/